# Непонятная единица измерения в приложении «Munin»

Tags: mysql, linux

Поставил «Munin», снял данные, получил результат.

В графике «MySQL queries – by day» по оси ординат написано «queries/seconds», а возле значений поставлена буква «k» (например "2.4k").
Что это за единица?

Просмотрел другие графики «MySQL queries» - ничего подобного не нашел.

Ну «m» - понятно – это минута, а «k»?

Comment: вероятно, «kilo» — тысяча. «2,4 тысячи запросов в день».

Comment: @Konstantin78, а что вам помешало заглянуть в документацию по Munin?

Comment: я смотрел, но просмотрел дайте пожалуйста прямую ссылочку, если не сложно,  
я для этого и "ходил" по документации "munin", но о единицах измерения ни чего не нашел :-(

Comment: тогда помогите пожалуйста, разобраться с двумя графиками [ссылка](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwhtpd5jownfjpn/graf.png?dl=0),  ну 2,4 тысячи запросов за с секунду я еще могу понять, хотя на том же графике, средняя величина по запросу "insert" = 429,51m (т.е. миллион?). А с нижним графиком тогда получается 33 миллиона за сек?

Answer (score 1):

> Ну «m» - понятно – это минута, а «k»?

вот [здесь](https://serverfault.com/a/123766/292034) разъясняют, что `m` — это *милли-* (десять в минус третьей степени).

а с `k` как раз понятно: это *кило-* (десять в третьей степени).